# How can I select the year in each row

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013, lightswitch-2012

I am trying to get list of Dates of the year of manufacture for determining the age of vehicles. My column looks like this:

[image]

and my code looks like this

```
 partial void Reports_InitializeDataWorkspace(List<IDataService> saveChangesTo) {

        // year of manufacture
        var yom = InsuranceQuotations.SelectedItem.mYear;
        var bday = Convert.ToDateTime(yom);

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int age = today.Year - bday.Year;
        if (bday > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;

        Age = Convert.ToString(age);

    }
```

I can only select the fist date in the column. How could I loop through all dates in the column?

Comment: What is type is "InsuranceQuotations"?

Comment: Thats the database table

Comment: Do you mean GridView?

Comment: The "InsuranceQuotations" displays the GridView of the table.

Comment: Can you show your ASPX code here so we understand more fully?

Comment: I am using lightswitch

Comment: Have you tried using the "Format Patterns"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674024.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the Insurance quotes:

```
foreach (InsuaranceQuote item in InsuranceQuotes)
{
    var yom = item.mYear;
    ....
}
```

**Note:** I'm making some presumptions here. One is that your grid of insurance quotes are of type `InsuranceQuote` and two that the data collection on the screen is called `InsuranceQuotes`.